# How to log messages with level ERROR

Tags: java, logging, exception, error-handling

```
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in go method: " + e);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
        }
```

1) How is it possible to log messages with Level being `ERROR` instead of `SEVERE` as I do above.

2) when logging message like the one above, should we call `e.toString()` or `e.getMessage()` ? which is more practical?

Answer (score 0):

1) It looks like you are using java.util.logging. There is no Level.ERROR in JUL. Severe is the right counterpart.
2) Better alternative is logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in go method", e). This probably will log the full call stack.

And finally... look at slf4j for logging